# Can't find the Build Action property for an image file in VS2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to get an image file to show in my WPF app for hours.  It shouldn't be this difficult.  I've looked around and what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522263/1366368) shows is what I'm seeing elsewhere, which is:

1. Add the file to the project directory
2. Add the file to the project
3. Set the image file's build action
4. Reference the image file relative to the project root directory as a relative path

However, it's not there.  I'm using VS2015 and I thought that might be the issue (that it's too old), but [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a0dcc9e-c1d3-4f61-8dec-5e143748454c/a-simple-question-regarding-proper-application-design-in-vs2015?forum=wpf) shows that it should have that property.

This is what I'm seeing on my computer:

[image: image showing the missing build action property]

The tooltip is showing the file path with the root of the path truncated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The image file must be part of a Visual Studio Project, not the VS Solution.

Comment: Thought I had tried that already.  Thx.